# Multiple series in HighStock charts

Tags: highcharts

I followed the below thread to solve the problem and it did not work for me.

I have simple requirement of ploting multiple series in a single chart (GBP_USD, USD_EUR and USD_CHF) at the load of the page/chart and once initial loading is completed, every second a call is made to server which returns an array with three values one for series1 (GBP_USD), second for series2(EUR_USD) and third for series3 (USD_CHF).

I started with ploting static graphs first, three series in one chart...

When I plot a single series in a chart then it works properly, but the moment i add more series it does not work. I could download the data in three different calls (following the compare example of HighStock) and the data is successfully received, but instead of getting curves, i am getting straight lines.
[![The image shows that with three names in Array, it plots straight lines][1]][1].
[![This images shows the chart when names array has only one value-GBP_USD][2]]
[2]

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/amonga141/04z9fj9p/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('in annynymous()');
  // var names = ['GBP_USD'], // Any One Currency, works [serise is as it should be]
  var names = ['GBP_USD', 'EUR_USD', 'USD_CHF'], // Three currencies [series are flat]
    seriesCounter = 0,
    seriesOptions = [],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

  console.log('starting to retrive data');

  $.each(names, function(i, name) {
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '<B>Loading please wait.. retrieving data</B>';


    var url = "http://134.213.48.26:8080/apitest/api/v1/ext/jsfiddle/data?callback=?&id=" + name;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      console.log("success with grabing json data for " + name);

      seriesOptions[i] = {
        name: name + ' Temperature',
        data: data,
        color: colors[i],
        type: 'line'
      };

      // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
      // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
      seriesCounter++;

      if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
        createChart();
      }
    });
  });

  // create the chart when all data is loaded
  function createChart() {

    console.log('in createChart()');
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    // Create a timer, to test how long this takes to load
    var start = +new Date();

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function(chart) {
            this.setTitle(null, {
              text: 'This chart was built on ' + new Date() + ' in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
            });


          }
        }
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
          type: 'hour',
          count: 1,
          text: '1hr'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 3,
          text: '3hr'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 12,
          text: '12hr'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 1,
          text: '1d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 3,
          text: '3d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 5,
          text: '5d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 7,
          text: '7d'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1m'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 3,
          text: '3m'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 6,
          text: '6m'
        }, {
          type: 'year',
          count: 1,
          text: '1y'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 2
      },

      yAxis: {
        type: 'linear',
        title: {
          text: 'Prices'
        }
      },

      title: {
        text: 'Historical Instruments Data '
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'Built chart at...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
      },

      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
        valueDecimals: 1
      },

      series: seriesOptions,

      exporting: {
        width: 1000
      }

    }, function(chart) {
      // Last point in graph...
      document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"; //hide the loading text

      showLastPointTooltip(chart);
    });
  };

});


function showLastPointTooltip(objHighStockchart) {
  // show tooltip for last point   
  var points = [];
  if (objHighStockchart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objHighStockchart.series.length; i++)

      points.push(objHighStockchart.series[i].points[objHighStockchart.series[i].points.length - 1]);


    objHighStockchart.tooltip.refresh(points);


  };
  console.log('DONE')

};
```

```html
<title>Multiple Currencies</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="loading" sytle="font-weight:bold;"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px">
```

I can control the data/format and frequency at server side and can change to any optimal way needed to make the solution work.

I also followed the below example line but line and changed the url to my local server and also changed Jquery verion and HighStock charts script tags, but got an error.[![Error when running the example in the below URL][3]][3]

[trouble plotting multiple series of data on highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716547/trouble-plotting-multiple-series-of-data-on-highstock#new-answer?newreg=26db98bf5d96412b9085693acdd78a2c)

The data from the server side for three currencies are as follows:

GBP_USD =[[1442485146000,1.55080],[1442485147000,1.55080],[1442485147000,1.55077],[1442485148000,1.55067],[1442485149000,1.55067],[1442485150000,1.55067],[1442485151000,1.55067],[1442485152000,1.55067],[1442485152000,1.55067],[1442485153000,1.55067],[1442485154000,1.55072],[1442485155000,1.55072],[1442485156000,1.55072],[1442485157000,1.55072],[1442485158000,1.55072],[1442485158000,1.55072],[1442485159000,1.55072],[1442485160000,1.55072],[1442485161000,1.55072],[1442485162000,1.55072],[1442485163000,1.55072],[1442485163000,1.55072],[1442485164000,1.55072],[1442485165000,1.55072],[1442485166000,1.55072],[1442485167000,1.55072],[1442485168000,1.55072],[1442485169000,1.55072],[1442485169000,1.55072],[1442485170000,1.55076],[1442485171000,1.55107],[1442485172000,1.55107],[1442485173000,1.55107],[1442485174000,1.55107],[1442485174000,1.55107],[1442485175000,1.55107]]

EUR_USD = [[1442485146000,1.13152],[1442485147000,1.13152],[1442485147000,1.13156],[1442485148000,1.13151],[1442485149000,1.13155],[1442485150000,1.13155],[1442485151000,1.13153],[1442485152000,1.13155],[1442485152000,1.13155],[1442485153000,1.13155],[1442485154000,1.13155],[1442485155000,1.13155],[1442485156000,1.13155],[1442485157000,1.13155],[1442485158000,1.13155],[1442485158000,1.13155],[1442485159000,1.13155],[1442485160000,1.13155],[1442485161000,1.13155],[1442485162000,1.13155],[1442485163000,1.13155],[1442485163000,1.13155],[1442485164000,1.13155],[1442485165000,1.13155],[1442485166000,1.13155],[1442485167000,1.13155],[1442485168000,1.13155],[1442485169000,1.13155],[1442485169000,1.13155],[1442485170000,1.13157],[1442485171000,1.13149],[1442485172000,1.13149],[1442485173000,1.13149],[1442485174000,1.13149],[1442485174000,1.13155],[1442485175000,1.13155]]

USD_CHF=[[1442485146000,0.96951],[1442485147000,0.96951],[1442485147000,0.96948],[1442485148000,0.96948],[1442485149000,0.96948],[1442485150000,0.96948],[1442485151000,0.96948],[1442485152000,0.96939],[1442485152000,0.96933],[1442485153000,0.96933],[1442485154000,0.96933],[1442485155000,0.96933],[1442485156000,0.96933],[1442485157000,0.96933],[1442485158000,0.96933],[1442485158000,0.96933],[1442485159000,0.96933],[1442485160000,0.96933],[1442485161000,0.96933],[1442485162000,0.96933],[1442485163000,0.96933],[1442485163000,0.96933],[1442485164000,0.96933],[1442485165000,0.96933],[1442485166000,0.96933],[1442485167000,0.96933],[1442485168000,0.96933],[1442485169000,0.96933],[1442485169000,0.96933],[1442485170000,0.96933],[1442485171000,0.96940],[1442485172000,0.96940],[1442485173000,0.96940],[1442485174000,0.96940],[1442485174000,0.96940],[1442485175000,0.96940]]

Any help of pointers will be highly appreciated...

Comment: The images in your question are missing, please add them.

Comment: You also really need to post your code as well (preferrably in a jsfiddle), otherwise nobody will be able to figure out the problem and help you.

Comment: Thanks Vicky- I will create the Jsfiddle and post the link.

Comment: @Vicky- Created a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amonga141/04z9fj9p/1/

Comment: I added the link to your question so that people can find it easily. Also see my answer below (the issue is not with your data format or anything like that, just a rendering issue).

Comment: @Vicky- Your explanation and solution are spot on. Searched through many places in Meta and parent site but still struggling to locate the **'Checkmark'** or **'accept answer'** button/link. I read that many users have mentioned that this option on this site is quite non-intuitive and Bad UX.

Comment: yes, it is a bit unintuitive. See this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5xR.gif. I hope that is clear enough?

Comment: basically, it should be on the left side of my answer, near the top (it'll be "unchecked" now and hence you will just see a thin outline of a tick mark, as shown in the gif I linked above; try zooming into the web page in case you're zoomed out too much).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because the variations in data in one series are too small to make any visual difference when compared to the difference among your different series. For example, your data in each series varies by less than +/- 0.001 while the difference between the 2nd and 3rd series is nearly 0.16, which is larger than 0.001 by a factor of 160x! You can even see this effect visually in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04z9fj9p/2/) (see the legend at the bottom of the chart? click on 2 of the series to hide them, and see how the 3rd one expands to fill the empty space).

There are 2 ways to solve this issue, both involving multiple y-axes:

#### 1. Use multiple overlapping y-axes

```js
var axisOptions = [];

$.each(names, function(i, name) {
  var url = "http://134.213.48.26:8080/apitest/api/v1/ext/jsfiddle/data?callback=?&id="+ name; 
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    axisOptions.push({
      title: {
      text: name + 'Prices'
    });
    // build seriesOptions and other stuff ...
  });
});

$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    yAxis: axisOptions,
    // other options ...
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04z9fj9p/3/)

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('in annynymous()');
  // var names = ['GBP_USD'], // Any One Currency, works [serise is as it should be]
  var names = ['GBP_USD', 'EUR_USD', 'USD_CHF'], // Three currencies [series are flat]
    seriesCounter = 0,
    seriesOptions = [],
    axisOptions = [],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

  console.log('starting to retrive data');

  $.each(names, function(i, name) {
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '<B>Loading please wait.. retrieving data</B>';


    var url = "http://134.213.48.26:8080/apitest/api/v1/ext/jsfiddle/data?callback=?&id=" + name;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      console.log("success with grabing json data for " + name);

      seriesOptions[i] = {
        name: name + ' Temperature',
        data: data,
        color: colors[i],
        type: 'line',
        yAxis: i
      };

      axisOptions.push({
        title: {
          text: name + 'Prices'
        },
      });

      // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
      // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
      seriesCounter++;

      if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
        createChart();
      }
    });
  });

  // create the chart when all data is loaded
  function createChart() {

    console.log('in createChart()');
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    // Create a timer, to test how long this takes to load
    var start = +new Date();

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function(chart) {
            this.setTitle(null, {
              text: 'This chart was built on ' + new Date() + ' in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
            });


          }
        }
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
          type: 'hour',
          count: 1,
          text: '1hr'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 3,
          text: '3hr'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 12,
          text: '12hr'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 1,
          text: '1d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 3,
          text: '3d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 5,
          text: '5d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 7,
          text: '7d'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1m'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 3,
          text: '3m'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 6,
          text: '6m'
        }, {
          type: 'year',
          count: 1,
          text: '1y'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 2
      },

      // NOTE: I added these lines
      // See the chart legend at the bottom of the chart now?
      // Click on 2 of the series to remove them, and notice how
      // the 3rd one expands to show all the points correctly
      legend: {
        enabled: true
      },

      yAxis: axisOptions,

      title: {
        text: 'Historical Instruments Data '
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'Built chart at...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
      },

      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
        valueDecimals: 1
      },

      series: seriesOptions,

      exporting: {
        width: 1000
      }

    }, function(chart) {
      // Last point in graph...
      document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"; //hide the loading text

      showLastPointTooltip(chart);
    });
  };

});


function showLastPointTooltip(objHighStockchart) {
  // show tooltip for last point   
  var points = [];
  if (objHighStockchart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objHighStockchart.series.length; i++)

      points.push(objHighStockchart.series[i].points[objHighStockchart.series[i].points.length - 1]);


    objHighStockchart.tooltip.refresh(points);


  };
  console.log('DONE')

};
```

```html
<title>Multiple Currencies</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="loading" sytle="font-weight:bold;"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px">
```

This simply assigns each one of your 3 series to a different axis. So in addition to creating the `seriesOptions`, you now also have `axisOptions` for each.

[image: solution 1]

#### 2. Use multiple non-overlapping y-axes

```js
var axisOptions = [],
    numAxes = names.length,
    // percentage of height left out for spacing the 3 y-axes
    axisSpacingPercent = 5,
    // percentage of height occupied by each y-axis
    axisHeightPercent = (100 - (numAxes - 1) * axisSpacingPercent) / numAxes;

$.each(names, function(i, name) {
  var url = "http://134.213.48.26:8080/apitest/api/v1/ext/jsfiddle/data?callback=?&id="+ name; 
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    axisOptions.push({
      title: {
        text: name + 'Prices'
      },
      // settings for multiple panes in the chart
      height: '' + axisHeightPercent + '%',
      top: '' + (i * (axisHeightPercent + axisSpacingPercent)) + '%',
      offset: false,
      lineWidth: 1
    });
    // build seriesOptions and other stuff ...
  });
});

$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    yAxis: axisOptions,
    // other options ...
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04z9fj9p/4/)

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('in annynymous()');
  // var names = ['GBP_USD'], // Any One Currency, works [serise is as it should be]
  var names = ['GBP_USD', 'EUR_USD', 'USD_CHF'], // Three currencies [series are flat]
    seriesCounter = 0,
    seriesOptions = [],
    axisOptions = [],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    containerHeight = $('#container').height(),

    numAxes = names.length,
    // percentage of height left out for spacing the 3 y-axes
    axisSpacingPercent = 5,
    // percentage of height occupied by each y-axis
    axisHeightPercent = (100 - (numAxes - 1) * axisSpacingPercent) / numAxes;

  console.log('starting to retrive data');

  $.each(names, function(i, name) {
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '<B>Loading please wait.. retrieving data</B>';


    var url = "http://134.213.48.26:8080/apitest/api/v1/ext/jsfiddle/data?callback=?&id=" + name;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      console.log("success with grabing json data for " + name);

      seriesOptions[i] = {
        name: name + ' Temperature',
        data: data,
        color: colors[i],
        type: 'line',
        yAxis: i
      };

      axisOptions.push({
        title: {
          text: name + 'Prices'
        },
        // settings for multiple panes in the chart
        height: '' + axisHeightPercent + '%',
        top: '' + (i * (axisHeightPercent + axisSpacingPercent)) + '%',
        offset: false,
        lineWidth: 1
      });

      // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
      // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
      seriesCounter++;

      if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
        createChart();
      }
    });
  });

  // create the chart when all data is loaded
  function createChart() {

    console.log('in createChart()');
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
        useUTC: false
      }
    });

    // Create a timer, to test how long this takes to load
    var start = +new Date();

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function(chart) {
            this.setTitle(null, {
              text: 'This chart was built on ' + new Date() + ' in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
            });


          }
        }
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
          type: 'hour',
          count: 1,
          text: '1hr'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 3,
          text: '3hr'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 12,
          text: '12hr'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 1,
          text: '1d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 3,
          text: '3d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 5,
          text: '5d'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 7,
          text: '7d'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1m'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 3,
          text: '3m'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 6,
          text: '6m'
        }, {
          type: 'year',
          count: 1,
          text: '1y'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 2
      },

      // NOTE: I added these lines
      // See the chart legend at the bottom of the chart now?
      // Click on 2 of the series to remove them, and notice how
      // the 3rd one expands to show all the points correctly
      legend: {
        enabled: true
      },

      yAxis: axisOptions,

      title: {
        text: 'Historical Instruments Data '
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'Built chart at...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
      },

      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
        valueDecimals: 1
      },

      series: seriesOptions,

      exporting: {
        width: 1000
      }

    }, function(chart) {
      // Last point in graph...
      document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"; //hide the loading text

      showLastPointTooltip(chart);
    });
  };

});


function showLastPointTooltip(objHighStockchart) {
  // show tooltip for last point   
  var points = [];
  if (objHighStockchart) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objHighStockchart.series.length; i++)

      points.push(objHighStockchart.series[i].points[objHighStockchart.series[i].points.length - 1]);


    objHighStockchart.tooltip.refresh(points);


  };
  console.log('DONE')

};
```

```html
<title>Multiple Currencies</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="loading" sytle="font-weight:bold;"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 900px; min-width: 500px">
```

This is similar to the solution #1, but spaces out the data across distinct non-overlapping y-axes.

[image: solution 2]